# Making jsvc work on OSX

Tags: java, macos, jsvc

I'm trying to reproduce the code written in this post:

[How to convert a java program to daemon with jsvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687159/how-to-convert-a-java-program-to-daemon-with-jsvc)

Without the fancy bash script.

I created the jar. This is the command I'm running:

```
jsvc -verbose -outfile tmp/example.out -cp /pathto/commons-daemon-1.0.13/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar:/pathto/MyProject.jar my.package.MyClass
```

Now... This does absolutely nothing. No output whatsoever. I even tried it with the script. No output again. And since jsvc doesn't throw any kind of error at all I have no clue what the problem is.

I even tried running it with `-server` or with `sudo`. Then I can see it appearing under processes but it still does nothing. Also verbose doesn't do anything and `JAVA_HOME` is properly configured.

Any clues / ideas? Did anybody make this work under OSX at all ever?

EDIT:

Logging is system out which according to that post and the manual of jscv should be captured in outfile.

Yes I did try setting an error file. Again no luck there was nothing in it it wasn't even created.

I tried giving it a user. And the code is exactly the same as in the linked issue that's why I didn't clutter this ticket with it.

I compiled my jsvc and have no tomcat installed.

Comment: No output in the example.out file, you mean? Did you try setting an error file? How is logging configured? I suspect you'll need to supply more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried running with the `-debug` flag? It spits out a fairly amount of useful information about why things may not be running as anticipated.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it worked to set `-outfile` and`-errfile` to standard out and standard error. Try:

```
-outfile '&1' -errfile '&2'
```