# Cannot load daemon when creating java service

Tags: java, daemon

I am trying to create a JAVA deamon like explained here
[How to convert a java program to daemon with jsvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687159/how-to-convert-a-java-program-to-daemon-with-jsvc?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I build it with the following command

```
 javac -cp .:commons-daemon-1.0.15.jar Main.java
 jar cfe  ServiceDaemon.jar example.Main Main.class EchoTask.class
 ./service.sh start && sleep 5 && ./service.sh stop
 cat /tmp/example.err
```

and I am getting this error

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: example.Main
     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
     at org.apache.commons.daemon.support.DaemonLoader.load(DaemonLoader.java:151)
 Cannot load daemon
 Service exit with a return value of 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `Main` class resides in the default package, but you specify `example.Main` as the main class, and there is no class with such name. Try to replace `example.Main` with just `Main`.

Answer (score 0):

Move `Main.java` into a directory named `example` and use

```
javac -cp commons-daemon-1.0.15.jar example/Main.java
```

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same problem, and resolved as follows.

In this example, "Main" class is packaged by "example".
The right way to make jar file is as follows.

javac -d . -cp commons-daemon.jar Main.java
jar cvf Main.jar /example/*.class

Then, include the generated Main.jar into -cp option of jsvc.