# install a jar with a servicename

Tags: windows, jar, nolio, udeploy

I have to start, stop a jar in a flow
 1. I have to stop it if it is already running and then start
 2. All this is being worked in Udeploy.
 3. I'm installing the jar using the below command.
    java -jar jarname.jar

When I use sc query servicename, it says the service is not installed as a Windows service. So, I can check, stop and start if it is only a windows service.

How can I install this as a windows service with a servicename to identify ?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687159/how-to-convert-a-java-program-to-daemon-with-jsvc Apache Commons Daemon can "daemonize" any Java program. On Windows it will create a Service. There are alternatives, for example Tanuki

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nssm](https://nssm.cc/download) to install a jar as a Windows service. No installation of nssm is needed. Just place it somewhere on the system (preferably somewhere in your PATH) and run it.

Here is the command to execute as a batch:

> nssm.exe install "(service-name)" "{java.exe path from jre}" "-jar
>   {jar-name-absolute-path}"
>
> nssm.exe set "{service-name}" AppDirectory "{jar-path}"